# mosquitto MQTT: How to restrict an user to read/write only dedicated topic?

Tags: security, mqtt, access-control, mosquitto

I would like to build a multi-user Mosquitto server.
The user should access only to its own topic.

For example, the user "dododo" should only write and read the topic:

```
users/dododo/#
```

It should not access (neither read nor write) any other topic.

Is it possible? I can not find how to do it. The best I have found it is "read-only" access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but it's not the most intuitive setting.

Set `allow_anonymous` to `false`. This has a side effect of making the default be disallowing access to topics; you'll need to explicitly allow access. This will affect all accounts on the broker.

Comment: Thanks. It is absolutely not intuitive. It works fine.

Comment: Glad it helped. If that solved your problem could you please accept the answer? That will help other people with the same problem know that this solution worked for you.